# Best Application Design for Software As Service

Tags: c#, database-design, asp.net-mvc-3, application-design, saas

Using ASP.NET MVC3 C# AND MS SQL 2008

I'm developing a Software As Service site.  It's a Car Inventory app for Car Dealers.  I have a few ideas of the architecture of the site but wanted a second opinion.

Each dealer will be restricted to a layout, but can upload a logo and select some color theme's.

At first I thought about creating separate sites for each dealer, but upgrading would be a nightmare.

So my thought is, one main site which dynamically changes based on the hostname.
ie. So if miamicars.carinventory.com is entered, they would see their color scheme and logo.

I would have one master database for the users and company settings, but a separate database for each site with the bulk of the data (car inventory, etc).  This way I can backup and handle each site's data individually, but the main code of the application would be in one place.

Also, each company would have a directory to store their individual images.

Any feedback would be welcomed.

Thanks

Comment: Here's your Feedback: lots of vague stuff.  No real question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considering these are multiple companies, I would recommend looking into [multi-tenant designs](http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2009/04/21/challenges-of-multi-tenant-enterprise-asp.net-applications.aspx). I know that it looks more complex but it helps you to grow the application cleanly as you grow. Here is another blog entry that is pretty interesting about [ASP.NET MVC](http://codeofrob.com/archive/2010/02/01/multi-tenancy-in-asp.net-mvc-why-do-we-want-to.aspx). Here is another interesting on in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff966499.aspx).

All in all, it is better if you are thinking about multi-tenancy to start from and grow it based on that. Particularly if you are going on Azure, it might be the only way to make it scalable.

HTH

Comment: This was some great information.  Now the question is, how do I dynamically create the databases when a customer (tenant) signups up?

Comment: You don't create new db. Instead, design the tables that has customer specific content to have an customer Id.7 /

Answer (score 1):

The way I see it from a database perspective you've got these options. Then again I've never written a multitenant application and gremlins surface during implementation.

### 1. Have a single database (cluster) for all the tenants.

Set up a single database, with master/replica clustering in the future. All tenants share the site, the separation of data is in the data itself.

- Simplify the management of the physical aspect of your application.
- Simplify the coding.
- Hamper scalability.
- Hamper performance (slightly).

### 2. Have a database per tenant.

Each tenant gets a database, possibly on a different database server.

- Much more of a pain to roll out new sites.
- Simpler to scale since the data will be partitioned naturally. Tenant A usually wouldn't need access to data from tenant B. Unless you're trying to write some kind of aggregate reports, in which case you get to write ugly sharding code.
- Good scalability. If a tenant can consume enough resources you can give them pretty high end dedicated hardware.

As far as the web servers, I'd look into using a custom SessionProvider with memcached or similar and using the servers themselves solely as processors that keep no state.

Answer (score 1):

In regards to database have you thought of using a NoSql database?

I am currently writing a very large web app with lots and lots (TBs of data) and am using MongoDb.

Here are some options:

- [MongoDb](http://www.mongodb.org/) - Very easy to set up
  and use. Super easy to scale and can
  do some very advanced queries. Has
  drivers for loads of languages
  including .Net.
- [Cassandra](http://cassandra.apache.org/) - Used    by facebook.
  Can infinately scale.    Not as rich
  of a query set as Mongo    and I've
  heard harder to set up but    no
  experience with it.
- [HBase](http://hbase.apache.org/) -       Built on top of
  Hadoop. Used by       Yahoo, open
  source via Apache. Little    more
  complicated

In regards to other stuff ASP.NET MVC is what I use. Very easy to deploy, and write code fast.

Comment: I've never used a NoSql database before but it seems very interesting.  But wouldn't MongoDB run on Unix?  I can't afford the learning curve now, but it would be something great to look into.

Comment: I am using MongoDb in a windows environment. Its extremely easy to set up and learning curve isn't too bad at all. I would seriously recommend it for stuff that needs to be fast, with lots of scalability. I still use MySql for basic stuff tho (login systems/eCommerce type stuff etc)